# Global Scope for Mock HTTPContext - CloudService Project?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, moq, azure-web-roles

I'm trying to set up a Unit Testing Framework for my WebRole project. I created a mock HTTP context and attached it to the controller that I'm trying to test as such:

```
var fakeHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var fakeIdentity = new GenericIdentity(username);
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(fakeIdentity, null);

fakeHttpContext.Setup(t => t.User).Returns(principal);
var controllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContext.Setup(t => t.HttpContext).Returns(fakeHttpContext.Object);

var controller = new HomeController();
controller.ControllerContext = controllerContext.Object;
```

My question is instead of attaching the mock context to one controller, can I mock up HTTP context for the project on a global scope, so all controller and utility classes have access to the mock HTTP context?

```
//Mock Context is attached to this controller. When Membership provider is accessed 
//from inside the controller it works fine. However when Membership Provider 
//is used from outside the Controller it returns null. 
public void controlerMethodinHomeController()
{ 
    //Returns Null
    var userID = Utility.GetUserId();

    //Returns valid UserID
    var userID = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
}

///Utility Class
public static Guid GetUserId()
{
  var user = Membership.GetUser();
  return user.ProviderUserKey
}
```

Comment: @chillax786 What exactly is 'global scope'? each unit test should deal with one unit of code, meaning one mvc action (method) cycle (block) in a controller. There is no 'global scope' in the unit test. If the code in your unit test goes through multiple classes, this is an integration test. It is certainly possible to build a mock http application that would instantiate and inject necessary dependencies, but we'd need to see the code under test and the test code to suggest a facility.

Comment: For a unit test, you can create a `CreateMockController<T>` method and then use this to have the faking code in one place

Comment: @zaitsman We get issues when we use Membership provider from our utility class. I have included the example in my original question.